# Slow down performance when using multiple dataSources in Spring Boot, JPA

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

I need to persist a lot of entities into database.
When I have only one data source.
I used  `JpaRepository.saveAndFlush(entity)` to persist data. I also used

```
@Autowired
EntityManager entityManager;
....
JpaRepository.saveAndFlush(entity)
....
entityManager.clear();
```

This technique helps me speed up performances.

But when I change into using multiple data source. I also use the same technique, it doesnt work anymore. It took several hours for creating data instead of 15 mins.

```
@PersistenceContext
EntityManager db1EntityManager;
....
JpaRepository.saveAndFlush(entity)
....
db1EntityManager.clear();
```

Here is my configure file

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(
        entityManagerFactoryRef = "db1EntityManagerFactory",
        basePackages = { "com.repository" }
)
public class db1Config {
   @Autowired
   private Environment env;
   @Primary
   @Bean(name = "dataSource")
   @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "db1.datasource")
   public DataSource dataSource() {
    DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
    dataSource.setDriverClassName(env.getProperty("db1.datasource.driver-class-name"));
    dataSource.setUrl(env.getProperty("db1.datasource.url"));
    dataSource.setUsername(env.getProperty("db1.datasource.username"));
    dataSource.setPassword(env.getProperty("db1.datasource.password"));

    return dataSource;
   }

   @Primary
   @Bean(name = "db1EntityManagerFactory")
   public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean db1EntityManagerFactory(
        EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder,
        @Qualifier("dataSource") DataSource dataSource)
   {
    HashMap<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<>();
    properties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto",
            env.getProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto"));
    properties.put("hibernate.dialect",
            env.getProperty("hibernate.dialect"));

    return builder
            .dataSource(dataSource)
            .packages("com.db1.model")
            .properties(properties)
            .build();
  }

   @Primary
   @Bean(name = "transactionManager")
   public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(
        @Qualifier("db1EntityManagerFactory") EntityManagerFactory db1EntityManagerFactory)
  {
    JpaTransactionManager transactionManager
            = new JpaTransactionManager();
    transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(db1EntityManagerFactory);
    return transactionManager;
   }
}
```

Performance result:

With 1,2k records:

1. Single data source for the first time create and reload data: 15 seconds
2. Multiple datasource: first time: 8,5 mins, reload data: 15 seconds.

With 65k records:

1. Single data source for the first time create and reload data: 15 minutes
2. Multiple datasource: first time: several hours

Detailed code for creating and reloading data.
For the single data source:

```
public class ProcessDataController {
public static final String CSV_URL = "C:\\abc.csv";
List<CSVSales> data = new ArrayList<>();
@Autowired
private ARepository aRepository;

@Autowired
private BRepository bRepository;

@Autowired
private CRepository cRepository;

@Autowired
private DRepository dRepository;

@Autowired
private ERepository eRepository;

@Autowired
private FRepository fRepository;

@Autowired
private GRepository gRepository;

@Autowired
private HRepository hRepository;

@Autowired
private IRepository iRepository;

@Autowired
private KRepository kRepository;

@Autowired
private LRepository lRepository;

@Autowired
EntityManger entityManager;
public void createData() throws IOException, ParseException {
    // BEGIN - For TESTING
    long step[] = new long[20];
    double timer[] = new double[20];
    ArrayList<String> table = new ArrayList<>();
    table.add("A");
    table.add("B");
    table.add("C");
    table.add("D");
    table.add("E");
    table.add("F");
    table.add("G");
    table.add("H");
    table.add("I");
    table.add("K");
    table.add("L");
    // END - For TESTING

    CSVReadAndParse readAndParse = new CSVReadAndParse();
    readAndParse.setUrl(CSV_URL);

    step[0] = System.nanoTime();
    data = readAndParse.getResult();
    step[1] = System.nanoTime();
    timer[0] = step[1] - step[0];

    for (int num = 0; num < data.size(); num++) {
        step[0] = System.nanoTime();
        A a = new A(data.get(num).getACode(), data.get(num).getAName());
        aRepository.saveAndFlush(a);
        step[1] = System.nanoTime();
        timer[1] += step[1] - step[0];


        B b = new B(data.get(num).getBCode(), data.get(num).getBName());
        bRepository.saveAndFlush(b);
        step[2] = System.nanoTime();
        timer[2] += step[2] - step[1];

        C c = new C(data.get(num).getC());
        cRepository.saveAndFlush(c);
        step[3] = System.nanoTime();
        timer[3] += step[3] - step[2];

        D d = new D(data.get(num).getDCode(), data.get(num).getDName());
        dRepository.saveAndFlush(d);
        step[4] = System.nanoTime();
        timer[4] += step[4] - step[3];

        E e = new E(data.get(num).getECode(), data.get(num).getEName());
        eRepository.saveAndFlush(e);
        step[5] = System.nanoTime();
        timer[5] += step[5] - step[4];

        F f = new F(data.get(num).getF());
        fRepository.saveAndFlush(month);
        step[6] = System.nanoTime();
        timer[6] += step[6] - step[5];

        G g = new G(data.get(num).getGCode(), data.get(num).getGName());
        gRepository.saveAndFlush(g);
        step[7] = System.nanoTime();
        timer[7] += step[7] - step[6];

        H h = new H(data.get(num).getHCode(), data.get(num).getHName());
        pRepository.saveAndFlush(h);
        step[8] = System.nanoTime();
        timer[8] += step[8] - step[7];

        I i = new I(data.get(num).getICode(), data.get(num).getIName());
        iRepository.saveAndFlush(i);
        step[9] = System.nanoTime();
        timer[9] += step[9] - step[8];

        K k = new K(data.get(num).getK());
        kRepository.saveAndFlush(k);
        step[10] = System.nanoTime();
        timer[10] += step[10] - step[9];


        L l = new L();
        L.setA(data.get(num).getNumberOfSale());
        L.setB(data.get(num).getSalesAmount());
        l.setC(a);
        l.setC(b);
        l.setD(c);
        l.setE(d);
        l.setF(e);
        l.setG(f);
        l.setH(g);
        l.setI(h);
        l.setK(i);
        fRepository.saveAndFlush(l);
        step[11] = System.nanoTime();
        timer[11] += step[11] - step[10];
        entityManager.clear();
    }
    double sum = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i <= 11; i++) {
        System.out.println(table.get(i - 1) + " time: " + new DecimalFormat("#.##########").format(timer[i] / 1000000000) + " seconds");
        sum += timer[i];
    }
    System.out.println("Reading data time: " + new DecimalFormat("#.##########").format(timer[0] / 1000000000) + " seconds");
    System.out.println("Total creating table time: " + new DecimalFormat("#.##########").format(sum / 1000000000) + " seconds");
}
public void deleteAllData() {
    lRepository.deleteAll();
    aRepository.deleteAll();
    bRepository.deleteAll();
    cRepository.deleteAll();
    eRepository.deleteAll();
    fRepository.deleteAll();
    gRepository.deleteAll();
    hRepository.deleteAll();
    iRepository.deleteAll();
    kRepository.deleteAll();
}
@RequestMapping(value = "/api/reloadData", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public  String reloadData() throws IOException, ParseException {
    System.out.println("------------------------" + acessDB);
    if (acessDB) {
        acessDB = false;
        long step1 = System.nanoTime();
        deleteAllData();
        long step2 = System.nanoTime();
        createData();
        long step3 = System.nanoTime();
        double time1 = ((double) (step2 - step1) / 1000000000);
        double time2 = ((double) (step3 - step2) / 1000000000);
        double time3 = ((double) (step3 - step1) / 1000000000);
        System.out.println("Delete time: " + new DecimalFormat("#.##########").format(time1) + " Seconds");
        System.out.println("Create time: " + new DecimalFormat("#.##########").format(time2) + " Seconds");
        System.out.println("Total time: " + new DecimalFormat("#.##########").format(time3) + " Seconds");
        acessDB = true;
        return "Done";
    } else {
        return "Busy";
    }
}
```

For multiple data source, I just change the @Autowired of EntityManager into @PersistenceContext like I said before.

and the main file.

```
public class EtlApplication implements CommandLineRunner {
public static boolean acessDB = true;

@Autowired
ProcessDataController processDataController;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(EtlApplication.class, args);
}

@Override
public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
    acessDB = false;
    processDataController.createData();
    acessDB = true;
}
}
```

Thank you for all your support.

Comment: Did you ever determine what the issue was with having multiple datasources and how it affects performance? We're facing the same issue.

Comment: Maybe you can use JVisualVM to find what is going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

While switching from one to two DataSources I experineced the same behavior. The performance dramatically went down.

It turned out that I also changed the datasource type to the vendors driver from `spring.datasource.db1.type: org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource` to `spring.datasource.db1.type: oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource`.

That was a bad idea..

Switching back to typ *org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource* it was fast as before.